# Hide code and indent lines

Tags: xcode

I was wondering if there is any plugin or even a native way to add these hide code and/or indent lines, just like in Dev C++, for example (image below).

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YI8SI.png)

The red arrow is pointing to the the button where we can hide a part of the code, making it easier to work.

Comment: Yes, it's called [code folding](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/recipes/xcode_help-source_editor/chapters/CodeFolding.html) in Xcode

Comment: Thank you!! It'll save me much time =)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a [cheat sheet](http://appletree.or.kr/quick_reference_cards/Apple-Mac-iOS/xcode-cheat-sheet.pdf), hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you!! It'll help me so much!! =)

Answer (score 4):

It is easy to do!

1. Holding cmd ⌘ button put your cursor on function declaration.

[image]

2. Then click and you will see Fold button in action list.

[image]